# OpenCart image manager issue after ssl change (1.5.6.4)

Tags: php, ssl, https, opencart

I have **OpenCart 1.5.6.4** and I've decided to add **ssl** to the website. I've changed both config.php files (root and admin) and also force all requests to be https. Website is working fine after some minor fixes except image manager (admin).

It doesn't show the images, I can see the folders, file names and size but not thumbnails. I've cleared cache, I can see that they are re-created but it still doesn't show in image manager.

I've checked the network, the image controller is called and its response is correct (thumbnail from cache folder) but a new http request is generated per image (thumbnail) with wrong url.

Instead of: `https://<website>/image/cache/data/<image>`

Url is:

```
https://<website>/admin/%EF%BB%BF%EF%BB%BF%EF%BB%BFhttps://<website>/image/cache/data/<image>
```

or as I see it in request view:

```
https://<website>/admin/https://<website>/image/cache/data/<image>
```

I couldn't find where the **HTTP_SERVER** or **HTTPS_SERVER** (they are the same) is appended.

**EDIT :**

I found where is the issue, I am still looking for a solution.

Path: admin - view - template - common

File: filemanager.tpl

```
$.ajax({
                url: 'index.php?route=common/filemanager/image&token=<?php echo $token; ?>&image=' + encodeURIComponent('data/' + $(element).find('input[name=\'image\']').attr('value')),
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function(html) {
                    $(element).find('img').replaceWith('<img src="' + html + '" alt="" title="" />');
                }
            });
```

The result **html** has **UTF-8 BOM** in front which causes this issue.

If you know how to remove it, let us know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem solved!**

UTF-8 BOM was 3 times which was very strange, there is only one response with UTF-8 text so if the problem was that it was supposed to be one BOM. I downloaded the files to my PC and I checked the **file encoding** (after 3 days of investigating network and AJAX code). They changed from UTF-8 without BOM to UTF-8 when I made the changes from the file manager of the hosting provider. It looks like it was adding the BOM to the response.

After changing the file encoding back to **UTF-8 without BOM** everything returned to normal. Images are shown to image manager and AJAX responses are clean.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check for hot link protection in your cpanel, whether you have listed https too.I had issue too with images, they were not displayed during checkout. Once I enabled the hotlink protection it worked.